# How to find the right smoothing capacitor for rectification circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, capacitance, rectifier, math, ac-dc

I am creating a power supply which will need to convert the 24vac to 5vdc. I am thinking of using a rectifier to convert ac to dc, then a capacitor to smooth out the voltage, then an LM2596-5 to drop it down to 5v. I am having trouble with selecting the right capacitor to smooth out the voltage. I saw this formula to find out the capacitor value

Current * Half Cycle time / acceptable voltage drop *1000 = C uf

When I plugged in my values

2 * 8.3 / 1 * 1000 = 16,600 uf

As you can see I get a ridiculous number and [this guy](https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/24vac-to-5vdc-conversion/#comment-129586) has used a 100 uf cap on his 24vac to 5Vdc power supply. My use is a smart thermostat that I am making. my max current that my setup takes is 1.4a but my rectifier is rated for 2a so that is why I am doing 2 amps. I am mainly confused on how the formula is giving really large numbers and why that guy happily chose 100uf

The Formula I got is from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAYKno16weE)

Comment: If you want only 1 volt of ripple, and have 1 amp load, re-charging only once per second, then you need ONE FARAD. For 1/120Hz, you need 1/120 = 8,333uf.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf why did you use 120hz?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 isn't 24vac is around 35vdc after rectification because of RMS

Comment: "isn't 24vac is around 35vdc after rectification because of RMS" - yes it, is and the unloaded output voltage may be even higher (better not be higher than 37V!).

Comment: @BruceAbbott So what will the DC to DC converter that you can buy do differently than my current configuration? What would you recommend to change?

Comment: Your words are little confusing - I assume by "than an LM2596-5 to drop it down to 5v" you mean "**then** an LM2596-5 to drop it down to 5v". If that is the case then you are intending to use a DC/DC converter (the LM2596), right?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, you are correct. Someone else in the comment section said to buy a DC-DC converter so I got confused on who am I messaging

Comment: @Aaliankhan  I suggested buying a converter unless you can make one better for US $3.66  Cap size can be reduced significantly at the expense of higher ripple current rated cap ( low ESR) meaning higher voltage ripple at 100Hz

Comment: And that uses 100uF input 220uF output and the same IC for the above LM2596 on a small board

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Those modules are really good an I used them all the time. It's just that they are a bit too big for my scenario and I would like to move the components around. I also like to learn about how this ac to dc power supplies work.

Comment: and the modules don't do rectification

Comment: I doubt you can reduce size of these modules without compromising heat rise and all you need is a bridge diode on input and possibly add low ESR cap up to 600uF. Moving components around may introduce bad EMI coupling and spurious responses

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I see your point there. by making it smaller I mean by using the full space that I have, since it is a circular PCB a rectangle doesn't utilize the full space. What if I use the schematic that comes with the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) on page 1, and use an ESR cap with a full bridge rectifier on the input. Do you think that is a good idea?

Comment: while researching I found a power designer created by texas instruments. It recommended this (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uo0KBThYEjP_ilvKJtJa2wyX19TBLnru) To rectify I will probably add a rectifier and a cap with 600uf. What do you guys think about this?

Comment: That’s DC to DC not AC rectifier to DC and primary cap ESR * C matters  with f. So dynamics are not simulated by TI. Consider any transformer/converter as an impedance squared converter ok? Source and load interact by voltage/current changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method of calculating C bulk for AC rectifiers is based on  energy storage required to prevent dropout if AC input cuts out for 1 cycle at max load.

The typical design on page 1 of your IC spec shows a **Cin=680uF** for a 12V to 5V @ 5A.

**Let’s how close I get to their recommended design.**

also Figure 23 shows the ripple current rating for the typical bulk e-cap must have a larger ripple current rating , for larger cap values to withstand the current surges. The RMS current rating of a capacitor is determined by the amount of current required to raise the internal temperature approximately 10°C above an ambient temperature of 105°C. This is NOT the value you want to use in the design , rather the max rated for which capacitors are rated for often 1500 hrs lifespan at the rated temperature.  Lower ESR, higher ripple current yet smaller C values are desired. Then ripple voltage in the cap can be further reduced by the circuit ESR added to the cap ESR.

However a lower input voltage a higher average current is needed to maintain a constant DC output power. So there are a lot of critical tradeoffs to balance in e-cap selection and the wrong one means poor reliability and efficiency from overall losses incurred.

### calculations

Thus using 50 Hz for one cycle= 20 ms. Your output power specified was **5V*1.4A=7W** and the suggested efficiency was 80%. So the required energy = E= P*t/80%= 180 mJ

The 24Vac bridge can produce 35V no load and about 24V average with lots of ripple so if we use this high ripple avg, \$E=1/2CV^2=180mJ\$ thus \$C=180mJ*2/24^2=625 uF\$

**Hmm pretty close.**

Next ESR or Ripple current.(rms)  I use the same value as DC current as expected value ( but not a hard startup).  so to reduce the stress on the heating up the cap, I am going to insert a power SMD resistor to this cap about 0.1 Ohm  hopefully for reliability purposes for the cap without creating losses elsewhere. Then choose a cap with an ESR
value of 10 mOhm so it doesn’t heat up much. this results in a  ESR*C=0.01*680uF=6.8us which I know is achievable in low ESR caps. (<10us)

### so my recommendation is 625 uF or 680 uF ,10 mOhm + Rs=100 mOhms in series.

Comment: Can you explain me how you calculated the energy? I live in Canada so I have 60 Hz. In the formula for the capacitor why did you multiplied the joules by 2?

Comment: I see there are lots of different formulas. do you know why there are so many formulas just for calculating one value

Comment: it is because there are **so many different tradeoffs**. I just made a simulation with my assumptions and model of your design and did not get the best efficiency but got it working with 100uF|30m + Rs=100m using Falstad’s sim (what @Transistor calls a toy) with 24Vac 50Hz input resulting 24Vdc rms then Buckboost to 5V A 1.4V validating every comment I made.

Comment: I live in Toronto just outside GTA... OH CA-NA-DAH , eh!  Look again C= 2* ....

Comment: To be honest I really don't know what you did in your formula. how did you get the joules? Why did you divide by 24^2 when you wrote before it is being divided by 1? Sorry if I am bugging you but I don't understand what you did.

Comment: @Aaliankhan simply rearrange energy formula and solve for C=E*2 / V^2 using 1 AC period

Comment: what about the joules

Comment: What about them? I defined the storage E for 1 cycle holdup with power interruption at max power at Vrms rather than Vpk 35V or 30V so Vmin can drop to 5.1V and still regulate out with feedback PWM

Comment: Who was the -1? and why do they fail to understand? Is their problem not my solution.  anyone ?  @LVW ?  Bruce? Transistor??

Answer (score 1):

Since the LM2596 is a switching regulator, the input current will be much lower than the output current. Assuming a minimum of 24VDC input and 83% efficiency the input current for 2A output at 5V would be 2/(24/5)*1/0.83 = 0.5A. Using your formula the required capacitance is then 0.5*8.3*1000 = 4,150uF.

If more ripple is acceptable then a smaller capacitance would be sufficient. You have around 10V of 'headroom' before the voltage drops below 24V, and even more before it gets close to the regulator's dropout voltage. For 10V ripple you only need ~415uF according to the formula.

However there is another reason for using higher capacitance - mains 'brownouts' and dropouts. Even though it might work OK with as much as 20V ripple under normal circumstances, a few low voltage or missing mains cycles could allow the capacitor voltage to drop too low, causing mysterious glitches in the device being powered. Higher capacitance holds the voltage up for longer to smooth over any momentary drops in the mains voltage.

Comment: I understand more thanks. Few questions. First is how did you calculate the amps. Second, I see that these capacitors are pretty large. Is it possible to add multiple smaller capacitance capacitors in parallel or series? I can build sideways but I don't want it to be too thick. if it's not possible then I guess I can lay it down sideways.

Comment: also, how does ray (the guy from the link in question) get away with his 100uf cap. his current draw is 1a

Comment: At 100% efficiency power in = power out. Power = Volts * Amps, so the current ratio is the inverse of the voltage ratio. The voltage ratio (from input to output) is 5/24 so the current ratio is 24/5. If 270uF is OK for 10V ripple then 135uF is OK at 20V, maybe even a bit less due to shorter time between half-cycles lower down the curve. Also your formula may be conservative, and his circuit might be drawing less current? I wouldn't be happy with it though.

Comment: You can put capacitors in parallel to make more efficient use of space. In series is bad because it reduces the total capacitance.

Comment: The 2496 switching regulator has large pulse currents, from 3.6 - 7A and this does not depend on load. You need to size the capacitor to ensure that you don't get dropouts. The formula described may work for linear regulators but will give you much to high a C value for a switching regulator. You need to include both the switcher pulse width and frequency in any calculation.

Comment: @Jack Creasey Good point. The datasheet recommends a capacitor ripple current rating of half the output current ie. 1A in this case - and has a chart suggesting a 270uF 40V capacitor would work. Popular LM2596 modules often only have 100uF, but perhaps expect more capacitance in the power supply. Yet another reason to have more capacitance!

Comment: [this datasheet](https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2008/12/01/semi_ap/manual/ons/ds/lm2596-d.pdf) from On Semi has only 100uF in their reference design! An improved version, or...

Comment: Why are you guys talking about the capacitors from the datasheet? I think those capacitors are for stepping the voltage down, not for smoothing the voltage after rectification.

Comment: I explained how 24Vac is 35V peak but with high ripple reduced down to 24Vdc on the bulk primary cap in my answer, the others are missing the point. But their examples in datasheet chose based on reducing current surge noise to source, not efficiently choosing the lowest C value for power dropout from a line transformer . i.e. AC-DC design vs DC-DC design rules. Capiche?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Why did you estimate the efficiency of 73%?

Comment: It's not an estimate, just an example. Actual efficiency is dependent on the voltages, inductor characteristics, capacitor esr etc. On review I see my input current calculation is out anyway (I changed the output current from 1.4A to 2A and forgot to update the result) so I will edit it to make the efficiency closer to what the datasheet graph suggests it might be.

Comment: @BruceAbbott did you made a power supply before? if yes, then what was your setup?

Comment: I have made many power supplies. They all followed the same plan - transformer, rectifier, filter capacitor, regulator. For switching regulators I usually use modules because they are cheap and I don't have to worry about getting the layout right. I use an oscilloscope to verify that the ripple voltage is satisfactory, and increase capacitance if it isn't (usually it's fine because I err on the large side in my calcs).

Comment: so you think a 4,000uf cap is normal?

Comment: 4,000uF is the right amount for 1V ripple, but your circuit can handle a lot more than that. So you have to decide how much ripple voltage you can accept vs the size of capacitor you can accept. I think 400uF is marginal, so I would at least double it to 800uF (or 1000uF, since that is a more common value). It doesn't hurt to 'over-engineer' a power supply for reliability (many consumer devices would last a lot longer if they didn't use the smallest sized capacitor they can get away with!).

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I will l be using a 1,000uf cap going in to a LM2596 circuit that is shown in the first page of the data sheet. Nice talking with you